# Access foreign key value in Django Rest Framework permissions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am coding a restaurant reviews app. User can write a review and add pictures to it. I am setting up permissions to `StarterPicsViewset` so only the author of the review can Update it.
So I set up a custom permission but as I run it, I have a `'StarterPic' object has no attribute 'restaurant_review_review_author_id'` error.

What I need is to get the `review_author` related to the `restaurant_review_id` so I can compare it to the `request.user`

Here is my models:

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):        
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=240)        
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
            

class RestaurantReview(models.Model):    
    review_author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                      on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        

class StarterPic(models.Model):
    restaurant_review = models.OneToOneField(RestaurantReview,
                                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name_1 = models.CharField(max_length=40)    
    picture_1 = models.ImageField()
```

My view:

```
class StarterPicsViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.InsidePic.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.InsidePicsSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly, IsOwnReviewOrReadOnly]
```

and my permissions:

```
class IsOwnReviewOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):          
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True    
        return obj.restaurant_review_review_author_id == request.user
```

Comment: `obj.restaurant_review_review_author_id` is not going to be transformed into related object. Try `obj.restaurant_review.review_author` to access review's author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StarterPic`  does not have such property like `restaurant_review_review_author_id` .

Try `obj.restaurant_review.review_author` to access review's author.